# Browse HTML file from local client in WebView

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx

I am mixing a JavaFX controls to swing application. I want to use `WebView` Control of JavaFX in Swing application . Can I browse the HTML files stored on the local hard disk of client as I can show with the help of `JEditorPane` in Java? Web View can display a web page from the internet but can it also browse the local system HTML files.

In `WebView` I am using the following code.

```
try
{ 
   final WebView webview = new WebView();
   webview.getEngine().load("http://oracle.com");
}
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

My query is instead of the web page from net how can I give the local HTML file in load method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
File f = new File(..);
// ..
final WebView webview = new WebView();
webview.getEngine().load(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
```

Comment: ya its working thanks . Can i add webview or webengine control to the container in swing.

Comment: See your follow up question [add webview on swing jframe form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487786/add-web-view-control-on-swing-jframe-form)