# Add WebView control on Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt, javafx-2, javafx

I am working on Swing application mixed with JavaFX control.

I have created a JavaFX control (`WebView`) to browse HTML files. But I want
     to know, how can I add this web view control on the container of a Swing `JFrame`?

Answer (score 32):

Given an already existing `jFrame`, the following code adds a new `WebView` and loads a URL:

```
// You should execute this part on the Event Dispatch Thread
// because it modifies a Swing component 
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
jFrame.add(jfxPanel);

// Creation of scene and future interactions with JFXPanel
// should take place on the JavaFX Application Thread
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    webView.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep a pointer to the `webView` element in Swing?

Answer (score 5):

[JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) allows you to embed JavaFX within your Swing application.